# Is it OK to use gray PVC electrical conduit for low voltage wiring?

Tags: electrical, conduit, low-voltage

I'm having my basement finished, and I am going to run conduit for low voltage (network) wiring in a week or two myself.  I have been planning on using gray PVC electrical conduit like [this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/JM-eagle-1-1-4-in-x-10-ft-PVC-Schedule-40-Conduit-67470/100196693), since it's available at Home Depot in many sizes with wide-bend fittings, and it seems like it'd be easier to mount and fish wires through a couple bends with it than with the flexible ribbed conduit.  However, when researching the project I came across [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LM9zzCLIZdY) for flexible conduit which states "bright orange components clearly signify a low-voltage installation."  So I have a few questions:

1. Can I use gray PVC conduit for low-voltage electrical stuff?  I know it's not kosher to use white PVC for high voltage.  Using gray for low voltage seems like it should be OK, since the stuff inside would be less dangerous.
2. Should I color-code the low voltage conduit, and if so what color should I use?  Orange (that's the color of the low-voltage brackets/mud rings)?  Could I spray paint the gray conduit?

Comment: In your area, does low-voltage mean 110V? And is 24V called extra-low voltage?

Comment: I'm in the US.  I'm using "high voltage" to refer to 120V mains electricity and "low voltage" to refer stuff like network and TV cable.

Answer (score 2):

Your method is legit and there’s no need for additional markings. All our phone and Ethernet are in EMT   I paint it blue to distinguish.

You can spray paint it if you really like overspray, but it seems to me like a recipe for a hatchet job unless you use a LOT of paint. Hatchet jobs are a code violation, NEC 110.12.

I would brush/roll it after dragging the PVC through some green Scotchbrite to mar the surface so the paint has something to grab.

Answer (score 2):

There is not voltage rating on conduit. You can use any voltage you care to. The difference between white "plumbing" PVC and "electrical" PVC conduit has to do with flame retardant properties necessary for the electrical conduit, so it is colored grey to let everyone know it is conduit, not water or drain pipe. Voltage is irrelevant.